# How to construct a (6,4,4) - code

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, binary

I am trying to calculate a (6,4,4)-Code C, where C is a binary(n,m,d)-code.

I understand the theory behind what C is, well I know how to write it at least. I know how to use the Hamming bound to check it is possible, however I don't get how I can write it in matrix form.

All examples I have found on here or elsewhere have had the first row in the question and have not given the minimum distance. I know we are after a 6x4 matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: Please remind me: is an $(n,m,d)$-code one with $m$ codewords or with $2^m$ codewords? I don't think there is a binary length 6 code with 16 codewords and minimum distance 4.

Comment: I believe m is the number of columns, n is the rows and d is the minimum distance. I thought there was only m codewords?

Comment: Lemonades, the number of columns and rows of ... what? A binary linear code of length $n$ and dimension $k$ (i.e. $2^k$ codewords) is often given in terms of generator matrix with $n$ columns and $k$ rows, and the codewords are linear combinations of the rows. Some authors use $[n,k,d]$ for such a code, some $(n,2^k,d)$. You probably mean the latter. Some describe a code by listing all the words as rows of a huge matrix. It sounds like you want the words to be columns? Sounds bizarre, but stranger things have happened :-) **Moral: Don't assume everybody knows the conventions of your source.**

Comment: Anyway, the question makes sense only with the interpretation that the length is six, number of codewords is four, and the minimum distance is four. A hint: Consider the even weight code of length three. It has four words. Duplicate the three bits to get words of length six.